# Metaprogramming: method_missing and __send__

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, method-missing

I've found an oddness in Ruby.  Using `method_missing`/`respond_to_missing?` to dynamically handle method calls initiated via `__send__` fails when Kernel defines the same method:

```
class Testerize

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if method == :system
      puts 'yay'
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method, internal)
    return true if method == :system
  end

end

t = Testerize.new
puts t.respond_to?(:system)
# Prints true
t.system
# Prints 'yay'
t.__send__(:system)
# Exception: wrong number of arguments (ArgumentError)
```

`Kernel.system` is somehow getting in the mix.  Does anyone know what's going on here?  I would have expected the `:system` "message" to get posted to the Testerize instance, hit `method_missing`, and voila.  Why isn't my `method_missing` getting called when using `__send__` when it *is* with direct invocation?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with '__send__' or 'send' we can even call private methods of the object.
```

In your script do:

```
t.private_methods.grep /system/
```

You will see `system` method, while with

```
t.methods.grep /system/
```

you will see an empty array.

`__send__` tries to call the private method inherited from Kernel in the inheritance chain, hence instead of using `__send__` use Ruby's `public_send` method.

Comment: Thanks Sachin.  That's it exactly.  I'd like to give Zach the accept, since he beat you to it by a minute or two, but yours is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the ancestor chain of your class (`Testerize.ancestors`), you will find:

```
[Testerize, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Since new classes inherit from `Object` by default, and `Object` inherits from `Kernel`, all of the instance methods available to `Kernel` are available in your instances.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but: ```Object.new.respond_to?(:system)``` is false, and the call to t.system does hit my dynamic code.  Kernel.system is a class-level method...

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. This is indeed strange. If you use `send` or `__send__`, you get the `Kernel.system` private method, but `public_send` will trigger the method missing call.

Comment: Also, deriving from BasicObject fixes things, all else remaining equal.  How the heck are class-level Kernel methods ending up in my call chain?

Comment: Kernel is a Module rather than a Class, so it might cause some behavior I'm not aware of. You can verify the existence of the private method in your call chain: `Testerize.new.private_methods`.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the key.  There's a private method :system lurking in the inheritance chain.  When I call ```t.system``` or ```t.public_send```, the call is confined to public methods, and thus works correctly.  When I use ```__send__``` it also checks for private methods, finds the internal #system, and so misses my method_missing entirely.  Can you update your answer so I can accept?  Thanks for the help!